# How to calculate number of turns, N for a gate driver transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, gate-driving

**Update:**
Hi, my TA helped my issue.
Thanks for everyone's help. It turns out, my area should be **12.2e-6**.(I accidently wrote 12.2e-5).

And, my understanding for ∆=2Bmax was wrong. The right way for me to choose my Bmax is Bmax<Bsat. And, the right concept was, ∆I=2Ipeak

And I wasn't given any specification for the inductance on the primary side. However, I'm still trying to understand this topic as it is my first electronics project.

---

I want to build a Switch Mode Power Supply (SMPS) and it requires a gate driver.
My parameters for the gate driver are:

**Vin= 15V,**

**f= 100kHz,**

**duty cycle= 0.35**

I'm using the 3C90 toroid as my gate driver transformer and I need to calculate the number of turns. The formula is:

**N= /∆**

The VTA used should be the worst case scenario, and for this, I made my duty cycle=50%

**My VTA=(15x0.5)/100k = 7.5xe-5**

[image: From link 1.]
From here, I took my saturated flux density, **Bsat=345mT** (100 °C)

[image: From link 2]
From here, it said that the peak flux density, **Bmax is 100mT**

And from the datasheet of the 3C90, the area is **A=12.2mm2**

[image]

So, I calculated my N as below:

**N= /∆**

**= (7.5e-5)/[(12.2e-5)(2)(100mT)]**

**=3.07**

**=3**

(where ∆=2Bmax)

However, this value is too low, and the TA said that it would cause some problems. He said the same thing to my friend who used N=11.

So, I was wondering if something is wrong with my calculations and analyzation of the datasheet.

Links:

1. https://elnamagnetics.com/wp-content/uploads/library/Ferroxcube-Materials/3C90_Material_Specification.pdf
2. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/650988.pdf

Comment: I got N=31 (30.7)  with your same equations and numbers.

Comment: What did you calculate your primary inductance to be?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you have to have enough INDUCTANCE that the pulse coupled thru that transformer will remain adequately FLAT that the FET remains well-driven ON.

Thus pulse duration is part of your design thinking.